# Изменение пароля для пользоватея root в phpMyAdmin

Tags: веб-программирование, php, пароль, phpmyadmin

Не заметил и выполнил след. sql:

```
grant select, insert, update, delete
on book_sc. *
to root@localhost identified by 'password';
```

и тем самым изменил пароль для пользователя root на password. Как в phpMyAdmin изменить пароль root на "" (пустой)?

Comment: Если из под рута настроен phpMyAqdmin то таким же запросом но с пустым паролем.
если доступа к базе нет - гугл в помосч есть целые мануалы как скинуть пароль рута.

Answer (score 2):

Решил данную проблему выполнением такого sql-запроса в программе HeidiSQL:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('');
```

Comment: выполнил sqlкоманду SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD(''); и терминал показал ошибку ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Answer (score 0):

Можно проще, без явного применения SQL запроса(если вы можете подключиться к базе):

в phpMyAdmin:

- нажать на ссылку "На главную"
- затем выбрать "Учетные записи пользователя" а там уже
- выбрать строку с необходимым пользователем и в столбце действия
- выбрать "редактировать привилегии" в появившемся окне будет ссылка
- "Изменить пароль" дальше интуитивно и так понятно

в HeidiSQL:

- Инструменты
- Управление пользователями
- далее интуитивно понятно